# Location of Gnome Automount

Tags: automount

1. Is there a way to tell nautilus where to automount specific devies - say, mount a device with `UUID=xxx-yyy` on `/foo/bar`?
2. Also, is there a way to disable/enable automount for specific devices (by specifying a UUID or device label)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You are better of asking one question at a time on this site. You may benefit from splitting your question. Since you already got an answer for the first I suggest you move the second to a new (proper) question.

Answer (score 1):

You can control where a device is mounted via the `/etc/fstab` file. Here are some examples from my `/etc/fstab` - it's up to you to adjust it for your situation.

```
# Part of the 1TB drive, for Rick's recovery
UUID=abcf5311-d080-4840-8056-ee4de9d62bfd /opt/Rick ext4    nodev,nosuid,user,noauto,rw
#
# My current mp3 player
UUID=70E0-C8E1 /home/walt/mnt/SANSAClip vfat    nodev,nosuid,noexec,user,noauto,rw
#
# My backup 1TB StoryStation
UUID=ff359af0-d996-4949-b27e-f24ce453c48c /backvol ext3 nodev,nosuid,noexec,user,noauto,rw
```

Because they all have the `noauto` option, they don't automount (except the mp3 player, and I don't even have `gnome-mount` installed).

Comment: This answers question 1 (note that you see to have to restart nautilus (nautilus -q), but not question 2.  Can you do automount selectively within nautilus (maybe with some HAL policy stuff that I don't understand)?